# Framework folders, but no libraries in app bundle with Qt 5.5 RC, 5.5 alpha still worked

Tags: macos, qt, cmake

I use cmake's bundle utilities to create an app bundle. With the [Qt 5.5 alpha snapshot](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/17/qt-5-5-alpha-available/), this worked fine. Using the [5.5 release candidate](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/06/22/qt-5-5-release-candidate-available/), it doesn't work anymore.

The proper folder structure for the Qt frameworks is still created, but the actual library binaries are missing. The CMakeLists.txt for the [minimal example](https://filetrain.de/bundletest.tar.gz) does it like this:

```
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME BundleTest)
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER local.BundleTest)

# Force the install prefix to have libraries installed into the bundle.
# This doesn't seem to work. Need to set the INSTALL_PREFIX manually in cmake.
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
set(QT_PLUGINS_DIR "${Qt5Core_DIR}/../../../plugins")
set(APP_BUNDLE "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/BundleTest.app")
set(binary_dest_dir "Contents/MacOS")
set(plugin_dest_dir "Contents/PlugIns")
set(qtconf_dest_dir "Contents/Resources")

install(TARGETS BundleTest
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    COMPONENT Runtime
)

# install a qt.conf file
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qt.conf"
    DESTINATION "${APP_BUNDLE}/${qtconf_dest_dir}/"
    COMPONENT Runtime
)
# install Qt's own translations
install(FILES ${QT_TRANSLATIONS}
    DESTINATION "${APP_BUNDLE}/${qtconf_dest_dir}/"
    COMPONENT Runtime
)

# Qt plugins
if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES "Debug")
    install(DIRECTORY ${QT_PLUGINS_DIR}/
        DESTINATION ${APP_BUNDLE}/${plugin_dest_dir}/
        COMPONENT Runtime
        FILES_MATCHING REGEX "(sqlite|imageformats|platforms)"
    )
else()
    # this branch intentionally left blank
endif()

# Use BundleUtilities to get all other dependencies for the application to work.
# It takes a bundle or executable along with possible plugins and inspects it
# for dependencies. If they are not system dependencies, they are copied.

# Directories to look for dependencies
# QT_LIBRARY_DIRS is usually empty, but that doesn't prevent 5.5alpha from working.
set(DIRS
    ${QT_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

# Now the work of copying dependencies into the bundle/package and also
# fixing up the Qt plugins we copied over earlier.
# The quotes are escaped and variables to use at install time have their $ escaped
# An alternative is the do a configure_file() on a script and use install(SCRIPT  ...).
install(CODE
    "
    file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_PLUGIN_LIST
        \"${APP_BUNDLE}/${plugin_dest_dir}/*/*${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}\"
    )
    include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(\"${APP_BUNDLE}\" \"\${QT_PLUGIN_LIST}\" \"\${DIRS}\")
    "
    COMPONENT Runtime
)
```

#### Steps to reproduce

To reproduce this with the example I linked above, set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug (to have the Qt plugins copied over) and CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to your build directory so that the libraries are installed into the app bundle. Then do the `make && make install` dance.

What can I do to create a working app bundle using the Qt 5.5 RC?

Comment: Have you considered just using macdeployqt?

Comment: @MrEricSir macdeployqt works fine, I had forgotten about that tool. Technically, this definitely answers my question/solves the problem, you'd deserve having it accepted if you post it as an answer. Still I'd love to know what change broke my previous setup...

Comment: I have the same problem in 5.5 final.